# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime during insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, linq-to-entities, calendarextender

I get the following error when i try to convert to date time.

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

```
 cost.b_date = DateTime.Parse(c_date.Text) ;//c_date.Text = 12/28/2012
```

Then i try

```
    string date = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",c_date.Text);
    cost.b_date = DateTime.Parse(date) ;
```

but i get the same exception how to fix this problem.

Comment: it may be due to wrong input value. Code is successfully running for correct value.

Comment: What is `c_date`? If you have calendar control or datetime picker just take the Date, not raw text..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `string.Format` when the *input* is a string is pointless.

If you know the format of the string, you should use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx). For example, for the string you've got, you could use:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "MM/dd/yyyy",
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You should consider:

- Is this user input? If so, use `TryParseExact` to detect user error more easily without an exception.
- Do you definitely know the exact format? If not, using [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) may be more appropriate.
- Do you definitely know the culture? If it's not the culture of the current thread, you should specify it explicitly.
- Do you *have* to get the value as text to start with? If you could use an alternative form of input which gives you the value as a `DateTime` to start with, that would be preferable.

Comment: I get this error 

`SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.`

Comment: My date time =`28/12/2012 12:00:00 AM`

Comment: @just_name: Well your question didn't mention SQL at all. You haven't shown how you're trying to insert the value into the database. I hope you're using parameterized SQL rather than just including the value directly in the SQL string...

Answer (score 2):

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(c_date.Text, "d", provider);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using DateTime.ParseExact.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(c_date.Text, "yyyy/MM/dd", null);
```